# How to design a list view showing name and online status in a single row

Tags: android, android-listview

I am creating an online chat app.In that I am using a list view to show the contacts who are online at that time. My problem is that i want to show the contact name and green color status icon or something like (as like in facebook or any other chat application) in a single row.

I don't know how to display contact name + a  green color on the right end of the listview 
can anybody help me solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a class that extends from `BaseAdapter`. There you can define your own Layout for each `listItem`.

So first you have to define a layout that contains a `TextView` for the contactname and e.g. a `ImageView`.

This Layout should  be customized in the `getView()` method of your `BaseAdapter`. 
But please [read this article](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) to ensure a "smooth scrolling" of you `listView`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

    <TextView
            android:text="Contact name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <View
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/green"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this is a very simple case where you want a custom item inside a `listview` , rather then giving you code I would suggest you to understand the concept of **layout inflation** where you can inflate almost all the container layouts with your designed layouts.

Google it you will yourself find a lot of examples in your case it seems a `textview` and `imageview` only.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friendname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="usename" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@drawable/profile"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom adapter for listview and set it to this listview.

This [tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Will show you how to do it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make custom layout for your `ListView` item like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<TextView
        android:text="Contact name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="green_circle_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following layout for your custom adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/status" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

To change the dinamically the image you can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) inside getView(...), from your custom adapter.
Ex:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_element, null);
    TextView statusTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    statusTV.setText("...");
    Drawable compoundDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.status);
    statusTV.setCompoundDrawables(compoundDrawable, null, null, null);
    return convertView;
}
```

And use a [viewHolder pattern](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166) for listView optimization.